# Stop jRecorder playing back after recording

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, jrecorder

I've been using jRecorder for a while now, it's pretty good considering how lightweight it is.

Now, I've got a case where I need to prevent jRecorder playing back the recorded audio after record. I've tried pretty much every function within jRecorder and the documentation is not *great*.

Anyone every encountered and got round this?

Here's the code, just standard jRecorder stuff really.

```
$.jRecorder({
    'swf_path': '/scripts/jrecorder1.1/jRecorder.swf',
    'host': host,
    'callback_started_recording': function() {
        $('.audio-recorder').addClass('recording');
    },
    'callback_finished_recording': function() {
        $('.audio-recorder').removeClass('recording');
    },
    'callback_stopped_recording': function() {
        $.jRecorder.sendData();
        $('.audio-recorder').removeClass('recording');
    },
    'callback_error_recording': function() {
        $('.audio-recorder').removeClass('recording');
    },
    'callback_activityTime': function(time) {
    },
    'callback_activityLevel': function(level) {
    },
    'callback_finished_sending': function(response) {
    }
}, $('.audio-recorder .audio-recorder-singleton'));
```

Comment: mattytommo - mattytommo's answer appears to be correct, you should accept it! ;)

Comment: @DarrenDavies Thanks Darren Davis, I think I will :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a day of trying almost everything on this, I finally found a solution. I thought I'd post it here in full as there are lots of comments on the jRecorder website on how to do this, but they are unanswered.

To do this, you need to do the following:

1. Go to https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder and download **everything** in the flash-fla folder. Make sure you match the folder of the flash-fla folder structure **EXACTLY** on your local machine.
2. Once you have done that, and if you haven't got it already, you're going to need to download Flash. I used the free 30 day trial to do this, you can also do the same.
3. Open up the Main.as file that you should now have in your local directory and delete line 160, which should be as shown below:

   ```
   private function recordComplete(e:Event):void
   {
       //fileReference.save(recorder.output, "recording.wav");


       //finalize_recording();

       preview_recording(); <----- **DELETE THIS**


   }
   ```
4. Now, you need to open up the AudioRecorderCS4-1.0.fla file in Flash and export the movie  (File -> Export -> Export Movie).
5. Once exported (and named so you can find it), reference/include in project your new SWF and change the `swfPath` of your jRecorder parameter to match the new SWF and voila! :)

Comment: Thank you Matty. Happy to see people reusing the code, editing  and customising for their own needs. Due to busy time I could not maintain the library well.

Comment: @mattytommo Hi. Could you make a download link to the new, edited AudioRecorderCS4.swf file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may download old version of jRecorder.swf file
from here [jRecorder.swf without preview](https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder/blob/dee290facfbf904778576c0ca98473281d033e73/javascript/jRecorder.swf)
so that you do not need to recompile fla file.

Hit Raw button to download it. This version does not have function jSendFileToServer
so you should comment it out in your jRecorder.js file.
WAV file will be submitted to server right after the recording stops.

Comment: I disagree with you. My text DOES provide neede answer for those who donot have Flash.